# Cannot write to the SQL DB ising PHP Insert Into

Tags: php, mysql

People,

I am sorry if similar question has been asked here. I am getting mad... I am trying to create PHP which is adding a record to DB. Please see below. When I run the code I get conformation of that there is a connection to the data base. But nothing gets added to the table... Buy the way recording part is copyed from phpMyAdmin. Supossed to work but does not. I have cheked data base and the table names.

FYI: I am trying to set web page on Godaddy hosting and am using cPanel.

Please help...

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","usedid","password","database");

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;


$sql = "INSERT INTO `mezenne_hourly` (`ID`, `TIME`, `DATE`, `USD_SELL`, `EUR_SELL`, `GBP_SELL`, `RRU_SELL`, `USD_BUY`, `EUR_BUY`, `GBP_BUY`, `RRU_BUY`) VALUES (NULL, CURRENT_TIME(), CURRENT_DATE(), \'88\', \'88\', \'88\', \'88\', \'88\', \'88\', \'88\', \'88\');";

/* $sql = "INSERT INTO `mezenne_db`.`mezenne_hourly` (`ID`, `TIME`, `DATE`, `USD_SELL`, `EUR_SELL`, `GBP_SELL`, `RRU_SELL`, `USD_BUY`, `EUR_BUY`, `GBP_BUY`, `RRU_BUY`) VALUES (NULL, CURRENT_TIME(), CURRENT_DATE(), \'88\', \'88\', \'88\', \'88\', \'88\', \'88\', \'88\', \'88\');"; */

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: You're not running your query

Comment: you didn't executed your query then how it will insert?

Comment: Thank you guys! Everything is working now!

Comment: @andrewsi, Thank you!

Comment: @Rat2good please mark and up-vote the answer. thanks.

Comment: people are not interested in marking the answer. Wastage of effort and time.Deleting my answer.